# Object Constructor Call Not Declared In This Scope

Tags: c++, class, constructor, compiler-errors

> I have managed to solve this myself by moving the #include for part_time.h to the top of the #include list. Why this made a difference, I have no idea.

I'm having an issue with one manual object construct call **after splitting my program into a makefile**. Each .cpp has an include for it's .h, and main.cpp includes every .h as well.

The relevant code is below. The errors are:

> main.cpp: In function ‘void add_part_time()’:
>   main.cpp:166:2: error: ‘part_time’ was not declared in this scope
>     part_time part_time1(name, forklift, annual_leave, sick_leave);
>     ^
>
> main.cpp:166:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘part_time1’
>     part_time part_time1(name, forklift, annual_leave, sick_leave);

Something weird I've noticed. If I delete the ; after the sick_leave definition line, then the only error I get is the same one asking about the missing ; and the other error disappears.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
    public:
        static int count;
        employee (std::string name);
        string name;
        ~employee();
};

employee::employee (string set_name) 
{
    name = set_name;
}

employee::~employee()
{

}

class dockhand: public employee
{
    public:
        dockhand (string set_name, bool set_forklift);
        float start_shift;
        bool forklift;
        float payrate;
        ~dockhand();
};

dockhand::dockhand (string set_name, bool set_forklift) : employee (set_name)
{
    forklift = set_forklift;
    start_shift = 4.00;
}

dockhand::~dockhand()
{

}

class part_time: public dockhand
{
    public:
        part_time (string set_name, bool set_forklift, int annual_leave, int sick_leave);
        float end_shift;
        int annual_leave;
        int sick_leave;
        ~part_time();
};

part_time::part_time (string set_name, bool set_forklift, int annual_leave, int sick_leave) : dockhand (set_name, set_forklift)
{
    end_shift = 8.00;
    payrate = 22.00;
}

part_time::~part_time()
{

}

void add_part_time()
{
    string name;
    bool forklift;
    int annual_leave;
    int sick_leave;
    name = "bob";
    forklift = true;
    annual_leave = 2;
    sick_leave = 3;
    part_time part_time1(name, forklift, annual_leave, sick_leave);
}
```

Yet the exact same format compiles just fine below with another class.

```
void add_casual()
{
    string name;
    bool forklift;
    name = "bob";
    forklift = true;
    casual casual1(name, forklift);
}
```

I'm stuck as to what the problem is. Commenting out the construct line makes it compile so it's definitely something there.

**EDIT** Changing the part_time part_time1(name, forklift, annual_leave, sick_leave); line to the casual constructor call makes it compile fine with a makefile. So even with the includes being correct there is still something wrong with that particular line.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help. I get a [completely different error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f201f8e68c9e4b8d).

Comment: On a side note, I think it's better to use class names that begin with a capital letter. For example, `class Part_time: public Dockhand`. It makes code more readable, especially when you have functions whose name matches the return type, like `part_time part_time1(name, forklift, annual_leave, sick_leave);`

Comment: Well I just properly converged it all into one chunk of code, and that compiles fine, but my makefile setup gives me the errors above still. Do you have any idea why that could happen?

Comment: It could be that you have defined `void add_part_time()` inside a file which doesn't #include, nor forward-declare, class `part_time`. When everything is in one file, no problem, but if you split things, the compiler doesn't know what `part_time` is. This is for your first error. As far as the second one is concerned, it might be related to the first one, or it might be a trvial syntax error. Hard to tell without seeing the exact code. I'd work on the first one first, and see what happens when you fix it.

Comment: I have an #include "file.h" for all the header files in main. There's a call further down for add_part_time that isn't throwing any errors. I guess there's some missing syntax somewhere then.

Comment: CAN'T REPRODUCE! This code compiles fine in my old MSVC2008...

Comment: The very first line states that it only throws an error when split into a makefile... which I am required to use, so I'm trying to figure out why it changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this myself by moving the #include for part_time.h to the top of the #include list. Absolutely nothing else was changed. Why this made a difference, I have no idea.

Comment: Then it means that class `part_time` is also required by one of the other files that you are including, so if you include `part_time.h` first they work, otherwise they will try to use something that hasn't been declared yet, and that they don't see yet, and therefore you get the error. Just search for all the places in your included files where you are using class `part_time` (or any other class that is declared in `part_time.h`) and you'll find it.

Comment: That's what I would've thought, I just can't see it. None of the other classes interact with each other except the hierarchy, which part_time is the final child of. Nothing depends on it except main.cpp, and part_time.cpp which both have the include.