# Are There Constraints on Includes of Header Files in Main.cpp?

Tags: c++, class, object, makefile, header-files

I've just managed to solve my own problem explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318064/object-constructor-call-not-declared-in-this-scope?). What I don't understand is the reasoning behind it. Basically after splitting a working program into a makefile, with all the includes being in the right place, one particular object construct call stopped working.

The solution ended up being to move the #include "filename.h" up higher in the list of 10 or so #includes in the main.cpp file.

Does this imply there is some kind of constraint? I wasn't aware of one, and since making this change the other header that has now taken bottom place is still working fine.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/URRrxamc)

**EDIT:** At the request of some users, I've added the bare minimum of code that is producing the error for me. It is still just over 300 lines though... The comments right at the top of the code explain how to make the error happen, but requires splitting of the code into separate files and using a makefile.

Comment: The pre-processor literally pastes all of the code in the include file `#include`d where it is included (unless stopped by a guard). So it's almost certainly a PEBKAC error.

Comment: Yeah that's what I had thought as well. I just can't figure out why moving an #include up a few spots would change anything.

Comment: Still not enough information to see what the problem was.

Comment: One of your headers probably uses something from that header without including it, so including it yourself beforehand fixes it.

Comment: Do the other files include the headers they depend on?

Comment: Yeah the entire header chain is complete, which is why it worked fine if I commented out the line creating a part_time object in the linked post. Every .cpp includes it's .h, every .h includes any .h that it requires (e.g hierarchy classes), and main included every .h file.

Comment: _"every .h includes any .h that it requires (e.g hierarchy classes)"_ Apparently not, or possibly there are some nasty circular dependencies. Whichever way you look at it, the answer is "poor code".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The constructor in question, part_time, follows the exact same hierarchy as the casual constructor. Both include dockhand.h, which includes employee.h. Other than another subclass of employee, that's the entire hierarchy. None of the classes have interaction between each other except for the fact that they are subclasses.

Comment: @DwayneH: Yet here you are with a situation you don't understand. Instead of repeatedly professing everything is fine, when it is not, present your minimal, complete testcase as previously instructed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just trimmed it down as well as I could, this second makefile only uses the 5 classes of the hierarchy, but still broke as soon as I moved #include part_time.h away from the top of the #include pile. How do I present a test case made up of separate files?

Comment: Dropping the number of #includes to 9 or less makes it work regardless of where the part_time one is. Any more and it breaks, it still seems like a limit of some kind.

Comment: _"How do I present a test case made up of separate files?"_ You don't. Reproduce it with one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Alright well I did that, the error happens whenever I have more than 9 includes and part_time isn't at the top. The only includes I dropped off to get it under 9 are two classes that have no interaction with anything else yet. Not sure what else I'm supposed to say to show that the includes appear correct.

Comment: You're supposed to show us your minimal, complete testcase. I don't know how else to say it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well I just updated the OP with it, but the code is still huge, even with cutting out most of the main functions. Which is why I was hesitant to do so in the first place.

Comment: If the testcase is still "huge", then you haven't finished composing it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well all it contains are all the class definitions, the functions that use them, and all the includes/guard statements. I've removed all the input functions and just wrote static ones to be used. It's not easy to cut down 15 separate files when the issue is to do with all of their includes. Changing the body of the classes might remove whatever dependency is causing the problem, which defeats the purpose of posting it.

Comment: Not really. Half the point of creating a testcase is precisely that: you may indeed discover the cause of the problem in doing so. _That is a good thing._ It is the definition of performing your own debugging before asking for our time. Change the body of the classes until they are really small _but still reproduce the problem_. If the problem disappears, _the thing you just removed is part of the cause_. That's a clue. Put it back, then use your new knowledge to decide what to try removing next. This is basic debugging.

Comment: Of course, all of this is explained in the [testcase help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which people keep refusing to read for no earthly reason

Comment: Well other than making constructors require less parameters, there's still no way to get it way down to what is expected. Empty constructors/destructors and all the includes for 10 or so classes is still over 100 lines. I'll just take your word for it being an include error. I don't see the need to spend an hour cutting out things when I have already solved it. I was just curious whether anything other than an include could cause it.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed constraints: one include file may need classes defined in another include file.  You must therefore ensure that the files are included in the correct order.

Example:

```
//======== File A.h ==========
class A {
   ...
};

//======== File B.h ==========
class B : public A {   // class B needs A to be defined first !!
   ...
};

//======== File main.cpp that works ========
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h" // ok:  relies on A and A is already defined
... 

//======== File ouch.cpp that fails ========
#include "B.h" // not ok:  relies on A but A is not yet defined !!
#include "A.h"
...
```

But fortunately, there are some good practices that avoid such pitfalls: use include guards in your headers, and in any header, preventively include the other headers required due to dependencies.  Here a [nice article](http://goodliffe.blogspot.be/2009/06/c-include.html) explaining this.

Comment: Ehm .... No. If `B.h` depends on `A.h`, then _it should include `A.h`._ If changing include order changes your program, _your code is wrong_. This is really important.

Comment: All my headers include guards, I came across that lovely problem a few weeks back. I can see what you mean about the #includes and reliance, but the error was coming from line 160ish in the main, so everything would've been copied in from the includes by then wouldn't it? Honestly I'd love to link the entire code, but I doubt anyone can be bothered looking over 300 or so lines for something that might just be user error.

Comment: @DwayneH: That is why a [minimal but _complete_ testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is required (as was explained to you by the Help Centre that you read carefully before asking). Also because you probably would have been able to work it out yourself if you'd made one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, or course !  I was about typing the example and the link to an article explaining this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did do that, which is exactly why I did solve the problem myself. However the results are inconclusive and I was curious as to why the #include order made a difference when the setup is definitely correct.

Comment: @DwayneH: I'm confused. Either you solved the question or you didn't. Which is it?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He put the link to a previous question in his first sentence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I solved the original question linked in the OP of this one. The reason for making this one is that the solution makes no sense, and I wanted to see if something other than includes could cause it.

Comment: @DwayneH: Right, so, for _this_ question, construct a minimal testcase! You say "I did do that", but you can't have done, because before you said "I'd love to link the entire code, but I doubt anyone can be bothered looking over 300 or so lines for something that might just be user error".

Comment: How exactly do I go about constructing a test case for this problem? I can literally cut and paste the include in main.cpp down one line and it breaks again. The other include it would swap with has no interaction with anything that would prevent the construct from calling without an error. The point of this question wasn't fix my code, I was curious if there was something else that would screw with includes, but evidently there isn't. I'll try and test it somehow, but my limited c++ knowledge is kinda leaving me short of any ideas.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "Ehm .... No. If `B.h` depends on `A.h`, then it should include `A.h`. If changing include order changes your program, `your code is wrong.`" I mostly agree. It's not necessarily "wrong" in the sense that a compiler isn't going to complain about it as long as your `#include` directives are in the right order. But I agree that having `B.h` include everything it depends on is The Right Thing To Do, and means that there is no specific "right order". (But I've read an article that actually advocates *not* doing this.)

Answer (score 0):

There are no inherent constraints, no. However, if the program is poorly written then it is possible for inclusion order to matter. This usually comes down to dependencies between headers not being properly handled with `#include` statements.